# Binding ListView in Xamarin Not Binding both Values

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

I have a list view binding to an sqllite list.

I can only get 1 label to display data

The following code

```
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="8" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TeudatZehut}" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding UserName}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

If i switch the first label to bind to UserName i get that data.. But never do i get both values??

suggestions?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

How you store and obtain data with database ?

The data grab from database should be a list of objects .

You can create binding on multiple labels and different properties .

Check the detailed sample in official link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows

Answer (score 0):

Your column looks pretty narrow. (8px) That's why I assume, the binding is working fine, but it's just not visible.

Change your column definition to

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

and you will see both values. After that, you can adjust the widths as you like.